# ServiceStack update caused all services to 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, servicestack

We've been running servicestack for quite a while now and have just gotten around to updateing OrmLite and the core ServiceStack libraries with it.

Everything was working great before the update but now the metapage and all services return a 404 - not found page.

Looking at the web.config nothing has changed.

Why is it now returning 404 pages and how do I fix it?

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.5.4.0" newVersion="6.5.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

AppHost is located on gist here: https://gist.github.com/JohnACarruthers/5366462

Routes 404ing seem to be all of them, metadata and REST urls specifically.

ServiceStack is hosted on mono's fastcgi server through apache, the config of neither has changed.

We're on the current nuget package now (3.9.43.0) and were on 3.9.25.0.

UPDATE:
Mysql.Data was throwing an OverflowException when executing raw SQL. Rolled back to and older version and things seem to work again. The bugged version of Mysql.Data was 6.6.4.0.

Comment: No one can answer this question. How do we repro this? What does your Web.config or AppHost look like? How are you hosting ServiceStack? What routes are returning 404's?

Comment: In addition to what @mythz said, what version were you using prior? What version did you upgrade to?

Comment: Updated with information requested though web.config and AppHost look close enough to stock that it shouldn't be causing issues.

Comment: Maybe ServiceStack isn't being initialized? Does Global.asax.Application_Start() method have (new AppHost()).Init() in it? Or add [assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ProjectX.API.App_Start.AppHost), "Start")] to your AppHost file.

Comment: response headers include an X-Powered-By ServiceStack header which I assume wouldn't be present if the AppHost hadn't been started or it'd throw an exception? Above the AppHost definition is [assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ProjectX.API.App_Start.AppHost), "Start")]

Comment: @JohnCarruthers try running it with `xsp4` in the root directory to see if it loads properly. Check your error logs to see if it didn't start up properly.

Comment: @mythz ahh, mysql is going crazy with an overflow exception - I wonder why fastcgi wasn't showing that to me :/

Comment: @JohnCarruthers cool, once you're back up and running just write + mark a small answer on what the issue was and what you did to help find it which will help future others with similar probs.